# Proving $C_{0} + C_1x +\cdots+ C_{n}x^{n} = 0$ has at least one real root in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> If $$C_{0} + \frac{C_1}{2} + \cdots+ \frac{C_{n-1}}{n} + \frac{C_{n}}{n+1} = 0\,,$$ prove that $$C_{0} + C_{1}x + \cdots+ C_{n-1}x^{n-1} + C_{n}x^{n} = 0$$ 
>   has at least one real root between $0$ and $1$.

I know how to prove the result by using the mean value theorem, but I am not understanding how the result from the mean value theorem allows us to conclude the final result. What I am asking is how does the existence of an $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$ mean that there exists a real root between $(0,1)$? All I can conclude from that is that there is an $x \in (0,1)$  such that the slope is the same as a secant line from the endpoints.

Comment: Various solutions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200034/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164818/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/363052/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/448173/42969

Comment: It is precisely from Baby Rudin that I took the exercise. The solution you posted all discuss using the integral. I was able to arrive at the conclusion, but I don't see any intuition as to why $f'(x) = 0$ means that a root of the original function exists (without the ideas of integration)

Comment: But $C_{0} + C_{1}x + ...+ C_{n-1}x^{n-1} + C_{n}x^{n}$ *is* the derivative, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164819/42969.

Comment: Set f' = P in the answer.  You may write its anti-derivative f.  You don't need a chapter on integration to do this.

Comment: @MartinR I see what you were getting at now. Sorry for the duplicate and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(x) = C_0 + C_1x + \cdots + C_n x^n$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 P(x) \, dx = C_0 + \frac{C_1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{C_n}{n+1} = 0.
$$
If $P$ doesn't vanish on $[0,1]$ then since it is continuous, it must be either strictly positive or strictly negative. In the first case, the integral would be strictly positive, and in the second, strictly negative.

Comment: Four identical questions with answers are not enough?

Comment: Apparently not...